# References for answers

Tags: discussion

Ok, I agree that most of math is magic.

But it would be nice if there were a special section for "textbook references" --

It doesn't even have to be built into the site, just a convention perhaps, like:

**References:**

- *Strang, Gilbert*.  **Introduction to Linear Algebra, 4E**.  Pages 82-85.
- *Weisstein, Eric W*. **Gould and Hsu Matrix Inversion Formula.** From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GouldandHsuMatrixInversionFormula.html

The idea is to provide an answer, yes, but to also put references at the end of each post for readers interested in further explanation.

It isn't to simply turn the site into a bunch of textbook references -- each answer should stand on its own -- but to let people know "where you got it" would be nice!

Comment: It would be nice if we each had the option to maintain a personal bibliography page somehow connected to our user profile.

Comment: I think you can just do this if you want to.  But bear in mind that many people are answering from their personal knowledge, and don't have any particular reference in mind or readily available.

Comment: On that answer I gave you in one of your questions, it's from a set of handwritten notes with an example showing how it's applied. Unfortunately I was not able to note down the refs. for this, and I'm (literally) far away from my books. So more or less similar to what Matt describes, except I got it from notebooks instead of memory. Don't worry, I'll get back to you on the provenance of the formula. ;)